# Listbox erasing existing contents on new add

Tags: delphi

With opendialog multiselect option turned on,I add files :

```
procedure TForm2.cxButton2Click(Sender: TObject); //add files
begin
if OpenDialog1.Execute then
    ListBox1.Items.Assign(OpenDialog1.Files);
end;
```

But,If I want to append one more file, the adding erases the previous listing that was listed in the listbox.This is probably by design but how do you get over this ?

Also,is there a way I can avoid adding duplicate entries ?

Comment: You aren't calling Add...... Have you read your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TStrings.Assign` replaces whatever is there with the new contents. It doesn't add.

To add a single item, use `Add`:

```
if OpenDialog1.Execute then
  ListBox1.Items.Add(OpenDialog1.FileName);
```

Use `AddStrings` to add multiple items at once while keeping what's already there:

```
if OpenDialog1.Execute then
  ListBox1.Items.AddStrings(OpenDialog1.Files);
```

Unfortunately, *TListBoxItems* doesn't have TStringList's Duplicates property, so there's no easy way to prevent duplicates. If you're only adding a single new item at a time, you can just manually check to see if it's already there.

```
if OpenDialog1.Execute then
  if ListBox1.Items.IndexOf(OpenDialog1.FileName) = -1 then
    ListBox1.Items.Add(OpenDialog1.FileName);
```

If you're adding multiple items and want to avoid duplicates, you can use an intermediate TStringList; it will have the (possibly unwanted) side effect of sorting the items, however.

```
var
  SL: TStringList;
begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    SL := TStringList.Create;
    ListBox1.Items.BeginUpdate;
    try
      SL.Sorted := True;   // Required in order to use Duplicates
      SL.Duplicates := dupIgnore;
      SL.Assign(ListBox1.Items);
      SL.AddStrings(OpenDialog1.Files);
      ListBox1.Items.Assign(SL);
    finally
      SL.Free;
      ListBox1.Items.EndUpdate;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: OpenDialog1 has no FileNames property.

Comment: @user763539 Would it not be more efficient for you to simply read the documentation? Or even your own code where you could have seen the simple error. It's as if you've not even read the code Ken wrote and made any effort to understand it. Do you view this site as a source of code to paste without reading? We like to help people, but really, you aren't making any significant effort here. Do try harder.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Typo. Corrected in both places.

Comment: @David Heffernan - no David, I am very much reading the code Ken wrote. Thank you for the downvote though ...@Ken White - SL.AddStrings(OpenDialog1.Files); does not add anything to the listbox.

Comment: No, it doesn't. The final `ListBox1.Items.Assign(SL)` does. I fixed another error in the code (that'll teach me to write code on the fly without reading it thoroughly afterward). Try it now.

Comment: Your comment to @DavidHeffernan and KenWhite actually confirms that you made no effort understanding what the code does, otherwise you would have been able to fix this and you would not complain about SL.AddStrings.